# What's the Android counterpart to iOS Calendars?

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, mobile

I've seen an iOS app that is able to add event to Calendar(start time and end time provided) and get reminder notifications. Just wondering what's the same thing to iOS Calendar on Android where I can do the same thing and receive reminders(notifications)? Any explanation or relevant link is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking for a calendar app?  There's dozens of them and its off topic here.  Are you asking how to programatically add to a calendar app?  Depends on which calendar they use.  This isn't the apple world where you can't make better versions of their software.

Comment: @GabeSechan, I'm asking if there is a default or built-in calendar in Android like iOS where you can schedule events and receive reminder notifications. If there is a built-in event scheduling and reminder mechanism in Android that's best. If there is not, maybe I need to do it myself. say run a backend service and check the start time of event periodically and push notifications etc.

Comment: You need to be clearer.  It sounded like you wanted an app suggestion, not asking about an API.  Retracting the close vote I made based on that.

Comment: @GabeSechan, apologize for the ambiguous wording. I'll try to be clearer next time. Thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html).

> The Calendar Provider is a repository for a user's calendar events. The Calendar Provider API allows you to perform query, insert, update, and delete operations on calendars, events, attendees, reminders, and so on.

Comment: seems spot on. Will research Calendar Provider now.